# Enable external request on IIS Express with https

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to enable external request on my web api running with iis express. To work with my xamarin project - Emulator.

I followed this doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api

And I tried to follow this one too :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/handling-url-binding-failures-in-iis-express#serving-external-traffic

But I can't run this command write in this doc : netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:44300 certhash= appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}

"Failed to add SSL certificate; error: 183
An existing file cannot be created. "

(I use the redirection http to https.)

Any adivce ?

Comment: Skip the netsh command when you already have the mapping.

Comment: Ok but I if I want to send request from my phone to my web api ? Do you have any doc because I can't found one...

Comment: What kind of web api? RESTful services can be called simply by the right URLs in your mobile web browsers.

Comment: In this case I Am just trying to connect at the main page to see if my phone can access to the web api, because I am using my phone to debug xamarin project. But if my phone can't bind on my web api then I can't use it to debug my xamarin project who is working with my web api.

Comment: I hope that you can do some extra test to learn what exactly was wrong. Try to set up a normal HTML test page on your IIS Express site, so that you can first ensure HTTPS connection can be made. Then you can move back to your own Web API project.